# JavaScript - How to change object keys in an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have an array of object :

```
let data = [
  { "date" : "17/03/2022", "count" : 2, "james@email.net" : 2 },
  {
    "date" : "17/05/2022",
    "count" : 2,
    "admin@email.com" : 1,
    "secretary@email.uk" : 1
  },
  { "date" : "17/07/2022", "count" : 7, "staff@email.us" : 7 },
];
```

I would like to remove "@" in the object key instead of the email address.

This is the **expected output** :

```
// Expected output:
data = [
  { "date" : "17/03/2022", "count" : 2, "james" : 2 },
  {
    "date" : "17/05/2022",
    "count" : 2,
    "admin" : 1,
    "secretary" : 1
  },
  { "date" : "17/07/2022", "count" : 7, "staff" : 7 },
];
```

Notes:

- james is from james@email.net (1st element)
- admin and secretary are from admin@email.com and secretary@email.uk, respectively (2nd element)
- staff is from staff@email.us (3rd element)
  and so on.
- email as object keys are dynamic, meaning it can be "johndoe@email.co.uk", "mary@email.net", etc.

I have tried, but yet not successful :

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let keys = Object.keys(data[i]);
  console.log(`key-${i+1} :`, keys); // [ 'date', 'count', 'admin@email.com', 'secretary@email.uk' ]
  
  let emails = keys.filter(index => index.includes("@"));
  console.log(`email-${i+1} :`, emails); // [ 'admin@email.com', 'secretary@email.uk' ]
  
  let nameList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    let name = emails[i].split("@")[0];
    nameList.push(name);
  }
  console.log(`name-${i+1} :`, nameList); // [ 'admin', 'secretary' ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function which splits the keys of the object keys at `@` and creates a new object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

Here's a snippet:

```js
const data = [{date:"17/03/2022",count:2,"james@email.net":2},{date:"17/05/2022",count:2,"admin@email.com":1,"secretary@email.uk":1},{date:"17/07/2022",count:7,"staff@email.us":7}];

const converter = o => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k.split("@")[0], v])
)

console.log(
  data.map(converter)
)
```

If `Object.fromEntries()` is not supported, you could use a simple loop through the array and then each object to create new objects like this:

```js
const output = []

for (const o of data) {
  const updated = {}
  
  for (const key in o) {
    updated[key.split("@")[0]] = o[key]
  }
  
  output.push(updated)
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and easily understandable, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this as short as simple:

```js
let data = [{
    "date": "17/03/2022",
    "count": 2,
    "james@email.net": 2
  },
  {
    "date": "17/05/2022",
    "count": 2,
    "admin@email.com": 1,
    "secretary@email.uk": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "17/07/2022",
    "count": 7,
    "staff@email.us": 7
  },
];
const refinedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
refinedData.map((el, i) => {
  Object.keys(el).map(e => {
    if(e.includes('@')){
      refinedData[i][e.slice(0, e.indexOf('@'))] = refinedData[i][e];
      delete refinedData[i][e];
    }
  })
});

console.log(data, refinedData);
```

Try this improvement to prevent shallow copy and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: This gave the expected output, but I could not assign the data.map(...) to another variable, like : `const modifiedData = data.map(...)`. Any advice about this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have improvised the code please check and let me know your thoughts

Comment: Does `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` mean you are doing a deep copy to not modify the original data? That being said, one should do a deep copy before reassigning it to another variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you are right, to prevent shallow copy of nested object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this?

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let element = data[i];
  let keys = Object.keys(element);

  let emails = keys.filter(index => index.includes("@"));
  for (let j = 0; j < emails.length; j++) {
    let name = emails[j].split("@")[0];
    let value = element[emails[j]];
    Object.defineProperty(element, name, { value });
    delete element[emails[j]];
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output missed the names, it looked like this : `[
  { date: '17/03/2022', total: 2 },
  { date: '17/05/2022', total: 2 },
  { date: '17/07/2022', total: 7 }
]`